# bottom overflowed by 4 pixels while trying to display icon and text below the icon in each tab in a flutter tab bar layout

Tags: flutter, tabs

I am trying to create a Tab Bar in flutter as follows:

```
TabController _controller;
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
    
      List<Widget> list = [
        Tab(
          icon: Image.asset(
            'images/dollar_world_grid_selected.png',
            width: 50.0,
            height: 50.0,
          ),
          child: Text(
            "Currency",
            style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(127, 127, 127, 0.4)),
          ),
        ),
        Tab(
            icon: Image.asset(
              'images/gold-bars.png',
              width: 50.0,
              height: 50.0,
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Gold",
              style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(127, 127, 127, 0.4)),
            )),
      ];
    
     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        // Create TabController for getting the index of current tab
        _controller = TabController(length: list.length, vsync: this);
    
        _controller.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = _controller.index;
    
            list = [
              Tab(
                icon: Image.asset(
                  _selectedIndex == 0
                      ? 'images/dollar_world_grid_selected.png'
                      : 'images/dollar_world_grid.png',
                  width: 50.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Currency",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(127, 127, 127, 0.4)),
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    _selectedIndex == 1
                        ? 'images/gold-bars-selected.png'
                        : 'images/gold-bars.png',
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "Gold",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(127, 127, 127, 0.4)),
                  )),
            ];
          });
        });
       }
    
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
        // by the _incrementCounter method above.
        //
        // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
        // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
        // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(200.0), // here the desired height
                child: AppBar(
                  // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
                  // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
    
                  title: Row(children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      'images/logobig.png',
                      width: 50.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                    ),
                    Text(widget.title),
                  ]),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    controller: _controller,
                    indicatorColor: Color.fromRGBO(43, 73, 193, 0.4),
                    tabs: list,
                  ),
                )),
    body: TabBarView(controller: _controller, children: [
    ]));
```

As you can see each tab contains an icon and a text below it. Unfortunately the output is the following:

[image]

As you can see the text is not displayed and I get bottom overflowed by 4 pixels. Any idea of how to display an icon and a text below the icon in each tab with the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce `4px` from you `Tab` Images like this

```
Image.asset(
  'images/gold-bars.png',
   width: 46.0,
   height: 46.0,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your **Tab widgets** with **SizedBox** or **Container** and set the **height** to *80 or bigger*. :)

Answer (score 0):

Increase tab bar widget hight in 4px

```
 appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(204.0), // change 200 to 204
            child: AppBar(
            //your code
```